# React-redux `useSelector` complains about Invalid Hook call

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am building a dynamic submenu for a dropdown using `React` and `Redux`. The plan is that when the user clicks on dropdown menu, an API call will be made and based on the response of the API, a submenu will be created. Here is my dropdown menu file

**MainMenu.js**

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import CreateSubMenu from './utils/CreateSubMenu.js'
import fetchSubMenuData from './actions/submenuAction.js'

function getSubMenu(menu, level){
  if(level == "level1") {
      const updatedMenu = CreateSubMenu(menu)
      return updatedMenu
  }

// entry level function
const DropdownMenu = () => {
     useEffect(() => {
        fetchSubMenuData();
       }, [])

    let menu = {"menu": "Locations", "submenu": []}
    const updatedNavigation = getSubMenu(menu, "level1")
}
```

Below is the file that contains a function that looks for API response and adds submenu to the menu. The API is call is made when the dropdown menu is clicked

**CreateSubMenu.js**

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

const CreateSubMenu = (menu) => {
    const subMenuData = useSelector(state=> state.addMenu)
}
```

But in **CreateSubMenu.js**, I get this error `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.` This error occurs when I use `useSelector` inside the function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the complete code for your component?

Comment: You do `const updatedMenu = CreateSubMenu(menu)` but `CreateSubMenu` does not return anything. If it retruns jsx you could do the following: `const updatedMenu = <CreateSubMenu {...menu} />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hooks cannot be called conditionally. In your code, you conditionally call CreateSubMenu if level == "level1"

```js
  if(level == "level1") {
      const updatedMenu = CreateSubMenu(menu)
      return updatedMenu
  }
```

This breaks the rule of hooks.

Instead, call the useSelector before the condition, and pass the value as an argument.

```js
const subMenuData = useSelector(state=> state.addMenu)
  if(level == "level1") {
      const updatedMenu = CreateSubMenu(menu, subMenuData)
      return updatedMenu
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I actually didn't post the entire code for the sake of simplicity. There are other API calls made as well and hence some more redux states. I want to target a certain redux state based on the `level` parameter. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: besides if I put `useSelector` before the condition check, its still inside the  `getSubMenu` function  and gives the same error.

Comment: this is what I actually did. I realised its okay to access the state before hand but pass on the state conditionally. But I will accept your answer for your efforts and for the sake for future viewers. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

In `CreateSubMenu.js` you probably export it in the wrong way - try adding

```
export default CreateSubMenu;
```

in the end of `CreateSubMenu.js` file